# How to send an image through HTTPPost?

Tags: android, apache

i'm creating an activity which needs to upload an image to a webservice using their api.

I found that if i use UrlEncodedFormEntity and send the image data through that. the webservice doesn't receive that. ( at least it will not be able to read that .)

In fact if i add some vars to send with the image data ( like name of the file, filesize ) they can be read from the webservice but the image data still doesn't appear if i try to read it serverside.

Right now i'm using UrlEncodedFormEntity with BasicNameValuePair as container for my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be it will help  you.
I've used the same functionality, but the web service was developed by me. I've post the image using the following:

1. I get the particular [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) icon and compress it in byte array like this:

   ```
   ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(10240);
   icon.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
   ```
2. Then create HttpPost and set the the entity.

   ```
   httpPostInstance.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(out.toByteArray()));
   ```
3. Check the "Content-type" header. You must properly set it to whatever your service expect.